# Create Android Room entity classes from DB file

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, android-room

I have a database file and queries. Using this I want to generate Room Entities.
Is there any tool available using which I can automatically generate room entities?

Comment: Software recs are off-topic. You can ask on [softwarerecs.se] instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no specific tools/plugins I remember which can handle the whole process altogether.

But yes, you can reduce efforts by the following process-

- Go to ***Android Studio -> File -> Settings -> Plugins***
- Search for "**Room Table Builder**" , install it and restart Android
  Studio.
- You have database file with you, have some data installed on each of
  your tables.  Now open the database file with [**DB browser for
  SQLite**](https://sqlitebrowser.org/dl/).
- Go to Db browser for SQLite ***File -> Export -> Table(s) to JSON...***
- Select all Tables and click Ok. After this, you will have to select
  the folder where you want to save all the JSON files. Do it.
- Now, open any .json ouput file and copy the content.
- Go to Android Studio, Right click on the package where you want to
  create Room Entity.
- Go in the new option "***Create Room Model from JSON***"
- Paste the copied .json file content in the block.
- Provide a Table name and click "***Create Room Table***".
- Done! You have created the `Entity` class for a Database Table. Repeat the
  copy and paste process for all the .json file, you had created from "DB
  Browser for SQLite".

Comment: Are there any plugins that let you create the POJO's from the JSON files created by the export step? The copy and paste method is lame especially if you have an existing database with a large number of tables.

Comment: Hi, Searching "Room Table Builder" is not giving any result. Can you please help

Comment: @Dex Room Table Builder not found

Comment: Plugin not found

Comment: This plugin is not already compatible with current AS 2021

Answer (score 4):

There is an Android Studio plugin: [SQLScout](https://www.idescout.com/download/)

SQLScout also features:

1. The ability to connect to databases in Android devices and the file
   system
2. A database schema explorer that displays the structure of databases
3. A SQL editor that provides all the features you’d expect from an IDE
   (syntax highlighting, code completion, reference navigation and
   refactoring) and the ability to execute SQL statements
4. A database console to view query results, edit table data, and
   export data to different formats (including Excel)
5. Database diagrams

You can refer [this blog](https://medium.com/@price.yvonne.86/quick-and-easy-migration-to-room-d40dbb142b51) for full steps.

Comment: Thank you @Derek for the answer. But it seems that this plugin is not free to use.